# dxtreelist jquery server-side paging dont work item skip and take

Tags: jquery, devextreme

i'm use devextreme   dxtreelist ver 21.2 and asp.net core
iam use dxtreelist  server-side paging but item skip and take is value null.
this my code .also this pic with parameter skip and take  in loadoptions no show
please see this  pic  debug[image]

```
    $("#treeOrganizationChart").dxTreeList({
                dataSource: store,
                keyExpr: "radif_post",
                parentIdExpr: "father_code",
                searchPanel: { visible: true },
                grouping: { autoExpandAll: true },
                selection: { mode: "single" },
                 remoteOperations: {
                    filtering: true,
                    grouping: false,
                    groupPaging: false,
                    paging: true,
                    sorting: true
                    
                },
             paging: {
                  enabled: true,
                  pageSize: 10,
                },
                pager: {
                  showPageSizeSelector: true,
                  allowedPageSizes: [10 ,24, 48,100],
                  showInfo: true,
                }
                 ..............
          }
/////////////////

    function GetData(path, method, key) {
    return new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
        key: key,
        load: function (loadOptions) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred(),
                args = {};

            ["skip", "take", "sort", "filter", "group", "groupSummary"].forEach(function (i) {
                if (i in loadOptions && isNotEmpty(loadOptions[i])) {
                    if (i === "filter") {
                        var filter = []
                                $.each(loadOptions[i], function (index, value) {
                                    filter.push({ Selector: value["0"], FilterValue:      value["filterValue"] });
                                });
                        }

                        args["filter"] = filter
                    }
                    else
                        args[i] = loadOptions[i];
                }
            });

         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem

The above structure(dxtreelist) does not have dxtreelist server-side paging, it is only for the dxdatagrid

the dxTreeList widget does not support paging: [T538226: dxTreeList - How to configure paging?.](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t538226/dxtreelist-how-to-configure-paging)

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t542872/dxtreelist-not-seeing-pagination-links-and-preventing-server-side-call-upon-expanding-node

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).